# how to recover pods with UnexpectedAdmissionError

Tags: kubernetes

My pods terminate automatic and finally I found the disk usage was 100% and auto dropped by kubernetes(v1.15.2).Now I am free disk and how to restart the UnexpectedAdmissionError pod like this:

[image]

I already tried this:

```
~ ⌚ 0:34:23
$ kubectl rollout restart deployment kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-z6z78
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.extensions "kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-z6z78" not found
```

do not work for me.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$ kubectl get pod kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-z6z78 -n kube-system -o yaml | kubectl replace --force -f -


pod "kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-z6z78" deleted
pod/kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-z6z78 replaced
```

From Documentation:

> `Replace` a resource by filename or stdin.
>
> JSON and YAML formats are accepted. If replacing an existing resource, the complete resource spec must be provided.
>   This can be obtained by
>
> $ kubectl get TYPE NAME -o yaml

It is worth checking `kubectl replace --help` as well.

Hope this help you.